# UITableView deleteRowsAtIndex & datasource troubles

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Happy 14th Baktun everybody!

This thing has been bugging me for a while, and I've googled to and fro, and also checked SO for an answer, but I just can't seem to grasp the answers and apply it to my app. If some of you would be so kind to help out, that would be appreciated!

I got the following function that deletes a cell from an UITableView when a stepper reaches 0.
I want the cell to be animated to the left, so when you press the - sign you'll see the cell swipe out of view. I set the `sender.tag` to the `[[cell stepper]setTag:indexPath.row];` in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
  - (void)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
{

    WinkelWagen *ww = [WinkelWagen sharedWinkelWagen];
    BWBand *band = [ww.winkelWagenArray objectAtIndex: sender.tag];
    NSDecimalNumber *nummer = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithFloat:sender.value];
    band.winkelmandjeAantal = nummer;
    [sender setValue:[band.winkelmandjeAantal doubleValue]];

    // Remove the cell and object from WinkelWagen if stepper.value turns 0
    if (sender.value == 0)
    {
        NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0],
                                     nil];
        [ww.winkelWagenArray removeObject:band];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        if ([winkelmandjeData count] == 0)
        {
            NSArray *addIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                                      nil];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
I've worked it out with `[[self.tableview]reloaddata]` but then the animation doesn't play. Can someone tell me how I should handle the data and the animation properly?

Thanks!

Comment: i m not sure whether it will workout or not just have a try. First **delete The Row --> Then Delete data from Array --> Then Delete the IndexPath** from Array.

Comment: That returns a:

 `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (16) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (16), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Comment: After some thought, I think it has something to do with the `[[cell stepper]setTag:indexPath.row];` and the `NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0],
                                     nil];`

function. 

For me, that was the only way to register the `UIStepper` and see which one I've been using. (so I would call `sender.tag` to get the `indexPath.row`). I reckon since sender.tag didn't change cos it's not updated, I might have to find a different way to get that indexPath.row value.

Comment: Did You try to Reload The table View After Deleting The Row ?

Comment: I updated the question again, with the working code. Though it doesn't animate.

Comment: If you use reloadData the animation won't work. You must call deleteRowsWithIndexPaths with something other than "animation none" Also, the exception means your data source must reflect the table view edits by the time you call endUpdates.

Comment: If I change it to UIAnimationStyleLeft, I see the cell go out of screen to the left, but it happens so fast, the reloadData cancels the animation and you don't see the tablecells scroll up to fill the gap, it just happens instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there something you could have a problem with, but don't know if it is an answer to your question. In your `if ([shoppingCartData count] == 0)` you are adding a row to the table, but the data source remains the same. That could result in a crash.

Also, before the `if`, your data source seem to be `ww.shoppingCartArray`, but in the `if` you are checking the count of `shoppingCartData`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah that was a bit messy from me :P. Somewhere in the code I make those two equal as I didn't figure out how to set the singleton store-array as the datasource. Didn't solve the issue, but thanks for making my code better! :D (Edited the question)